# 3 monitors XFX Radeon R9 270X

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

**Problem:**
Hi there. I am trying to connect a third monitor to my computer, but as soon as I plug the third screen in, my other monitor gets disconnected.
In the windows Display Settings, it detects that I have a third monitor connected, but when I try to chang ethe "Multiple displays" from *Disconnect this display* to *Extend desktop to this display*, I get the error:

"*The display settings could not be saved. Please try a different combination of display settings*"

**Info**:
Of what I've been able to find on this topic, the third monitor *(and up)* would need to be connected with **displayport**, and my graphic card supports 6 screens. Graphic card: **XFX Radeon R9 270X**.

The cables I am using:

- Main monitor: **Displayport** to **HDMI**
- Second monitor: **HDMI** to **HDMI**
- Third monitor: **DVI** to **DVI**

I am using a Displayport to HDMI, not Displayport to Displayport, and I do not know if this is causing the problem...

Any help is appriciated, been struggling with this for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayPort-HDMI connection is indeed the cause of the problem. The graphics card supports only two TMDS (DVI/HDMI) connections. Because your cable doesn’t have an activate converter but is made for DP++ (Dual-mode DisplayPort), it requires the card to output HDMI on its DisplayPort connector.

So you either need a DisplayPort-capable display or an active converter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OSBDVF8). They are of course more expensive compared to a “dumb” cable.

Comment: This does not seem to work. I bought the exact cable and I get the exact same problem. I tried multiple combinations of the screens, as of what I've heard, the Displayport screen has to be the third or up... Still without luck...

Comment: What "exact cable" did you buy?

Comment: This one: https://www.av-cables.dk/displayport-til-hdmi/displayport-til-hdmi-adapter-kabel-sort.html

Comment: Looks correct, but they don’t mention it’s an active converter. Unfortunately, there aren’t any manuals specifically for your graphics card, so I don’t know whether it is more restricted than others.

Comment: I'm gonna call the company, ask them - thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to solve this issue or not. I have the exact same setup and was able to get it working.

I have all 3 displays setup in Extended mode.

3rd Display was showing up as INACTIVE.
Had to tinker with Windows>Display settings>Multiple Displays.

In multiple display, I selected the option to Duplicate 1 and 3. To my surprise the 3rd display became Active even though it was Duplicate of Display 1.

With some more tinkering I was able to get the 1 and 3 to be extended. The settings do seems to be  bit of a crap-shoot. Sorry not able to document it. I am just happy it is working with none of the displays being duplicated.

Good luck.